# Running a docker from an ECS container instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I already have an ECS cluster setup with tasks that runs my app on ECS container instances.
Now, given a docker image, I need to be able to run it from inside my app, and it must run on the same EC2 instance my app runs on.

I read that running docker inside a docker is not recommended and that the best practice is to create a sibling docker.
It means my EC2 instance should run 2 containers:

1. My app, maintained be ECS.
2. the docker image my app decided to run.

How do I achieve such a setup? Does ECS supports this?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that with ECS. It would be possible if you didn't need it to be on the same host instance by scaling the desired count of a service up and down. You could also do it manually like you would with any Docker, but my guess is that if you do that, resource allocation will get screwed up as ECS isn't managing that. I assume the reason you need it to be on the same host is to share files mounted from the host? Maybe using EFS could mitigate that requirement.

Comment: @dpwrussell the reason I need to be on the same host is because I will be sending a receiving data at a very high bitrate between the 2 containers. If I run them on seperate machines I will unnecessarily have to pay a lot more for better network card.

Comment: Yeah, that's tricky. I don't suppose the task could be divided up so that it initially runs a task which determines what containers are necessary to do the real work? You could then have various different tasks with pairs of containers (A+B, A+C, A+D, etc) that you could scale up to begin the actual job.

Comment: @dpwrussell Thanks for the tasks idea. We also came with this one but rejected it. The manually invoked dockers are created by the users of our app, so the solution has to be more flexible and automatic than just creating a set of predefined tasks.

Comment: I think you're going to have to use a more manually constructed infrastructure then probably. I don't know if even Kubernetes can manage dynamic sibling container deployment.

Comment: In theory, how would your system work with regards resources? Launching siblings is going to be fine when it's a small number perhaps, but presumably if you get more users at once, then you'll run out of resources.

Comment: @dpwrussell Each such docker is going to do heavy CPU work. So I expect that the load balancer and the auto scaling will do the work as in a regular scenario.

Comment: The load balancing is the issue. It wouldn't know if it should route a user to a container as the load balancer (unless custom in some way) wouldn't know if there were spare resources to launch the sibling containers.

Comment: If you get a chance, I'd love to hear what you came up with to achieve your goal and if you were able to do anything with my suggestions?

Comment: @dpwrussell We took a step back eventually. Each docker will run on a different machine and the bitrate will be reduced by doing some sort of compression. That means we will pay more for CPU than necessary but we feel we went with a more streamlined approach. None of the other options felt like a feasible solution. Regardless, your suggestions are appropriated so thanks for that.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1):

I had a couple of ideas. I don't know if these will work, but I'm writing it as an answer as it's pretty long!

**One Idea**

Container A: Your containers that are always running.
Container X: One of a variety of different containers that are not always running.

Start by defining a Task definition for A and all the different types of X.

One thing you can do when running a task is specify certain constraints. On container A you could use the API to determine which EC2 instance a container was running and then specify that as a constraint when running a task of one of the X types.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html

It would probably happen that you'd try and run tasks where the constraint is impossible (if the instance is already fully committed on resources), but at least you'd get an error.

**Even simpler idea**
Have the container A task reserve enough resources for itself plus some number of container Xs. Then just launch the instance manually by mounting the docker socket inside the container and communicating with that. You'd have to manually make sure you didn't overcommmit on resources.

**Issues with both**

What I was getting at in my comment about resource allocation is that however you do this, if you are load balancing container A, the load balancer has no way to know that the container A they are routing to has no capacity to spin up additional container Xs. Say an EC2 instance has 4CPUs and 8GBs of RAM and container A uses half of that. Lets say a container X uses 1 CPU and 2GBs of RAM. Once 2 container X siblings are running on the same instance, there is no scope to start more, but the load balancer would not know that when routing user traffic to container A. Hope that makes sense. So you might need to extract the public facing interface to a container that does nothing else, lambda, etc. This layer could be aware of which container A instances have spare capacity to launch container Xs.